# Pandas pivot table flatten multiindex by appending one index to column name

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if I'm using the right terminology here to get what I want.

Starting DF

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'UUID': [1,2,1,4], 'TYPE': ['A','A','B','C'], 'D':[8,9,10,11]}
)
```

```
    UUID TYPE   D
0   1    A      8
1   2    A      9
2   1    B      10
3   4    C      11
```

Then I pivot it. The way the view looks is what I want to show in my notebook

```
pd.pivot_table(test_df, index=['UUID','TYPE'])
```

```
              D
UUID    TYPE    
1       A     8
        B     10
2       A      9
4       C     11
```

And then I want to re-shape the pivot table to look like this for some output

```
UUID  D_A    D_B    D_C
1     8      10     null
2     A      null   null
4     null   null   11
```

How do I get the above table and what would be the right "pandas" way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should get there from test_df not after you pivot (even though all your really doing is sorting on UUID and Type...)

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'UUID': [1,2,1,4], 'TYPE': ['A','A','B','C'], 'D':[8,9,10,11]}
)

df2 = pd.pivot_table(test_df, index='UUID', columns= ("D_" + test_df['TYPE']))
```

That essentially gives you what you want, now you just need to adjust the multilevel index.

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)
df2.columns.name = None
df2.reset_index()


  UUID  D_A   D_B   D_C
0   1   8.0   10.0  NaN
1   2   9.0   NaN   NaN
2   4   NaN   NaN  11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do using creating a 'flag' column first:

```
# create a flag column
test_df['flag'] = 'D' + '_' +  test_df['TYPE']

# pivot the data
f = pd.pivot_table(test_df, index=['UUID'], columns=['flag'], values='D').reset_index()
f.columns.name = None

   UUID  D_A   D_B   D_C
0     1  8.0  10.0   NaN
1     2  9.0   NaN   NaN
2     4  NaN   NaN  11.0
```